# Defining constant and passing it as a parameter results in "discards qualifier from pointer target type"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This has been asked so many times in the forum but I need to clarify the concept behind this. I am declaring a const NSString *key = @"SomeConstValue"; and passing that to a method which accept a NSString pointer type. However it results me in some warning "discards qualifier from pointer target type". What does this mean? How am I suppose to create an constant and pass it to this method?

Comment: I've retagged this, since it doesn't appear to be about Objective-C++ per se, or the runtime specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case you describe you are discarding the "const" qualifier (passing a const NSString * to a method expecting a NSString *).

NSStrings are always immutable, so you can safely declare the constant as "NSString *".
If you want to trigger compiler warnings when assigning values to the variable, declare it as "NSString * const".

Comment: Thanks for the reply diciu. My intention is to make the constant non changeable thought the .m file. If you are familiar with java I'm looking for the public static final equivalent in objective c.

Comment: Use "NSString * const". It's what Apple uses to declare string constants. (E.g. NSView.h:APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * const NSFullScreenModeAllScreens;)

Comment: Yes I did that I get the above warning then

Comment: const NSString * is not the same as NSString * const. It's the difference between a pointer to a const NSString and a const pointer to a NSString.

Comment: @Dilshan: You must be doing something wrong. `NSString* const` will not generate a warning when you pass it as a parameter because it means the **pointer** won't change, not the content of the string. As parameters are pass by value, the pointer is copied so there is no danger of it changign.

Comment: Yes true thanks for the reply. I have made the mistake. It works perfectly now. Thanks.

Comment: Dilshan: `const NSString *` *is* the same as `NSString const *`; maybe that's what you tried. The correct type is `NSString *const`; with the `const` keyword after the pointer, the `const` keyword applies to the variable (which is why that's what you want), not to the pointer in the variable (which is why the compiler considers that important enough to warn about implicitly discarding).

Comment: Yes Peter you are correct. I tried the earlier approaches and kept on getting the warning. But the later approach worked fine. I did the mistake like you mentioned above. Thanks fro your reply.